# Perfect circle buffer on QGIS Madeira 3.4

Tags: qgis, buffer, network

Working on a road junction I would like to make a perfect rounded circle buffer of 1 km around this junction in QGIS 3.4. Here is what is look like now.

[image]

Comment: do you want your circle centred at the centre of the junction?

Comment: I need a circle of 1 km radius for every extremity of the road.

Comment: then you have that it isn't a circle (and can't be)

Comment: Is there another way to change this buffer (after being created) into a perfect circle?

Comment: There is no such thing as a perfect circle. And if you create one that's close to perfect in one projection, it will be far from it in another.

Comment: You could get the centroid and maximum extent of your geometry, then buffer the centroid by 1 km plus the max extent. Still, some points of the circle will then be farther than 1 km from the nearest part of the junction.

Comment: depending on the intended use for the buffer, either A) you must keep this non-circular shape. or B) you can create a new point layer centered in the road features and then draw the 1km buffer (of course it will not, and cannot, be exactly 1km from all edges while remaining a perfect circle) If you want  perfect circle you will have to compromise with the length measurements. you have to decide what is more important: precise distance measurements, or a nice looking circle.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I understand you correctly, go ahead
The original data, see figure 1

[image]

create a polygon type from your data

2) Run the data analysis tool on it> Vector geometry> Minimum enclosing circles see figure 2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new editing session you can create a new polygon circle that estimates the size of the buffer.

You can make it more exact by referencing the coordinate points at the far points of the buffer.

You won't be able to make a circle that is exactly the same distance from every extremity of the road because it is an uneven shape.

Answer (score 0):

1) Calculate the centroid of the feature.
2) Calculate the distance from the centroid to the farthest extent of the feature. 
3) Make buffer that is 1 km plus the distance from step 2.